# power in the context of multiple tests

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-power

I need to do a power calculation for a planned experiment, is my reasoning correct?

- 12 comparisons are planned
- success is defined as at least one H0 rejection
- Because a very specific missingness pattern is to be expected, I simulated one comparison (i.e. 2 groups) under Ha with the expected effect size. Because the intent is to do 12 comparisons, the significance level was corrected per Bonferroni. This gives me an estimate of the power for conducting 1 comparison, with corrected significance level. Let's call this `pow1`

Under the assumption that the tests are independent, is it correct to say that *if a number of X out of 12 Ha are true, the chance of rejecting at least one H0 is $1-(1-pow1)^X$*?

Is it OK to have a range of power values, each of the power values depending on how many Ha are assumed to be true? For example depending on what the subject matter experts think is realistic.

For example, if my `pow1` is only 0.2, this gives me the power for only 1 true Ha, and about 0.93 if all 12 Ha are true.

I tried to find justification for my reasoning, but I can't find any, so I am doubting myself and hence the question.

Also, what if the tests are not entirely independent? I don't expect a concrete answer to this last question, but pointers to good references would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct, and you can easily demonstrate this through simulation as well:

```
iters <- 1E6
N <- 12              # Number of comparisons
n <- 10              # Obs. per group in each comparison
alpha <- .05/N       # Bonferroni-corrected alpha

k <- 5               # Number of Ha that are true
(powx <- 1-(.8**k))  # Expected power

# Standardized effect size needed for 20% power in one comparison at corrected alpha
d <- power.t.test(n=n, sig.level=alpha, power=.2)$delta

set.seed(1)
obs <- lapply(seq_len(iters), \(.) {
   ctrl <- matrix(rnorm(N*n), ncol=n)
   test <- rbind(
      matrix(rnorm(k*n, mean=d), ncol=n),
      matrix(rnorm((N-k)*n), ncol=n)
   )
   
   list("ctrl" = ctrl, "test" = test)
})

# Group indicator for collated matrices
grp <- factor(rep(0:1, each=n)) 

sig <- vapply(obs, \(l) {
   any(genefilter::rowttests(cbind(l$ctrl, l$test), grp)[,3] < alpha)
}, logical(1))

(powo <- mean(sig))
> 0.681052
```

If you repeat the above with `d=0` or `k=0` (null hypothesis true everywhere) you'll see that this maintains FWER. You can vary `k` to change the number of true alternative hypotheses.

When using the Bonferroni correction it does not matter what the correlation between your tests is, the price you pay for that is that it is about as conservative a correction as you can get. There are other FWER-controlling methods such as Holm's step-down, Hochberg's step-up, and Hommel's step-up (in order of increasing power), but all except the first are only valid under no or very weak correlation between tests. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures) and the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/p.adjust) for R's `p.adjust` has a lot of references.